# Select second last record with Laravel - eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

How can i select the next to last record added to a table. I can select the last record like -

```
transition::order_by('created_at', 'desc')->first();
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
transition::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->skip(1)->take(1)->get();
```

Comment: I needed to chain first() in the end but this did the trick, Thanks

Answer (score 4):

**or try this one**

```
DB::table('transition')
  ->where('transition_id', '<=', $id)
  ->orderBy('transition_id', 'desc')
  ->skip(1)
  ->first();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have auto increment ID field it is better to user that field, because created_at is very often same for more rows :

```
transition::orderBy('id', 'desc')->skip(1)->take(1)->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use this

```
\App\Transition::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->skip(1)->first()
```

Answer (score 1):

second to last for unique column

```
DB::table('transition')->where('transition_id', '<=', $id)
->orderBy('transition_id', 'desc')
->skip(1)
->take(1)
->first();
```